# Publishing a snapshot JAR to Artifactory Maven repository fails to deploy

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

My team is trying to deploy a JAR generated by a Jenkins job to a repository in our Artifactory Pro 7.6.2 instance that is set up as a Maven snapshot repo. However, when performing the actual upload of the generated JAR file from the project the deploy fails with an error 500.

This is what is in the console output of the Jenkins job:

```
[consumer_0] Deploying artifact: http://<artifactory URL>/maven-dev/com/example/example-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1-javadoc.jar
[consumer_1] Deploying artifact: http://<artifactory URL>/maven-dev/com/example/example-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1-sources.jar
[consumer_2] Deploying artifact: http://<artifactory URL>/maven-dev/com/example/example-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1.jar
[consumer_1] Deploying artifact: http://<artifactory URL>/maven-dev/com/example/example-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1.module
[consumer_0] An exception occurred during execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 500 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
 Status code: 500
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ConsumerRunnableBase.run(ConsumerRunnableBase.java:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 500 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
 Status code: 500
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:685)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:355)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:39)
    ... 2 more

[consumer_1] An exception occurred during execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 500 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
 Status code: 500
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ConsumerRunnableBase.run(ConsumerRunnableBase.java:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 500 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
 Status code: 500
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:685)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:355)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:39)
    ... 2 more
```

On the Artifactory server side, the following is shown in log when this fails (this is repeated for each file that failed, just putting one example here):

```
2020-08-18T22:27:33.042Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [6c7ca1a483dd3f03] [o.a.r.d.DbStoringRepoMixin:291] [tp-nio-8081-exec-407] - Couldn't save resource maven-dev:com/example/example-client/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/example-client-0.0.1-20200818.222406-1-sources.jar, reason:
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.dao.NodesDao.getChildren(NodesDao.java:247)
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.FileServiceImpl.loadChildren(FileServiceImpl.java:272)
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.tree.FolderNode.getChildrenItemNode(FolderNode.java:74)
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.tree.FolderNode.getChildren(FolderNode.java:56)
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.folderContainsPoms(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:422)
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.createSnapshotsMetadata(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:210)
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculateAndSet(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:179)
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataCalculator.calculate(MavenMetadataCalculator.java:154)
    at org.artifactory.maven.MavenMetadataServiceImpl.calculateMavenMetadata(MavenMetadataServiceImpl.java:86)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5156.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy242.calculateMavenMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.repo.interceptor.MavenMetadataCalculationInterceptor.afterCreate(MavenMetadataCalculationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.artifactory.repo.interceptor.storage.StorageInterceptorsImpl.afterCreate(StorageInterceptorsImpl.java:69)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.afterCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbStoringRepoMixin.invokeAfterCreateInterceptors(DbStoringRepoMixin.java:407)
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbStoringRepoMixin.saveResource(DbStoringRepoMixin.java:245)
    at org.artifactory.repo.db.DbLocalRepo.saveResource(DbLocalRepo.java:162)
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveResourceInTransaction(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1915)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor477.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.saveResourceInTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveResource(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1903)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor526.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.saveResource(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItemWithContent(UploadServiceImpl.java:574)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItemWithProvidedContent(UploadServiceImpl.java:554)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItem(UploadServiceImpl.java:429)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadFile(UploadServiceImpl.java:420)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadArtifact(UploadServiceImpl.java:402)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.adjustResponseAndUpload(UploadServiceImpl.java:223)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.validateRequestAndUpload(UploadServiceImpl.java:189)
    at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.upload(UploadServiceImpl.java:132)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor520.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.artifactory.request.aop.RequestAdvice.invoke(RequestAdvice.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238.upload(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doUpload(RepoFilter.java:284)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:176)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthenticationAndContinue(AccessFilter.java:413)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.authenticateAndExecute(AccessFilter.java:301)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:176)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryTracingFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryTracingFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jfrog.storage.wrapper.ResultSetWrapper.invoke(ResultSetWrapper.java:85)
    ... 109 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained due to a deadlock, cycle of locks and waiters is:
Lock : ROW, NODES, (2975,6)
  Waiting XID : {230127895, S} , APP, SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = ? AND node_path = ? AND depth = ?
  Granted XID : {230127897, X} 
Lock : ROW, NODES, (991,272)
  Waiting XID : {230127897, S} , APP, SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = ? AND node_path = ? AND depth = ?
  Granted XID : {230127895, X} 
. The selected victim is XID : 230127895.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.closeOnTransactionError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.movePosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: A lock could not be obtained due to a deadlock, cycle of locks and waiters is:
Lock : ROW, NODES, (2975,6)
  Waiting XID : {230127895, S} , APP, SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = ? AND node_path = ? AND depth = ?
  Granted XID : {230127897, X} 
Lock : ROW, NODES, (991,272)
  Waiting XID : {230127897, S} , APP, SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = ? AND node_path = ? AND depth = ?
  Granted XID : {230127895, X} 
. The selected victim is XID : 230127895.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.Deadlock.buildException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentLockSet.lockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentLockSet.zeroDurationLockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.AbstractPool.zeroDurationlockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.locks.ConcurrentPool.zeroDurationlockObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.RowLocking2nohold.lockRecordForRead(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.heap.HeapController.lockRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.heap.HeapController.lockRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IRowLocking3.lockRowOnPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IRowLocking3._lockScanRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.index.B2IRowLockingRR.lockScanRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.BTreeForwardScan.fetchRows(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.btree.BTreeScan.fetchNextGroup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BulkTableScanResultSet.reloadArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BulkTableScanResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexRowToBaseRowResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ProjectRestrictResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BasicNoPutResultSetImpl.getNextRow(Unknown Source)
    ... 115 common frames omitted
```

The Jenkins job is a declarative multibranch pipeline and the Artifactory deployment is done via the following code within the Jenkinsfile:

```
...
    dir("mavenOut/snapshot/"){
        rtBuildInfo(maxBuilds: 10)

        rtUpload(
            serverId: "artifactory", 
            spec: """{
                "files":[
                    {
                        "pattern": "**/*",
                        "excludePatterns": ["*maven-metadata.xml", "*.sha1","*.sha256","*.sha512","*.md5"],
                        "target":  "maven-dev/",
                        "flat": "false"
                    }
                ]
            }"""
        )

        rtPublishBuildInfo(serverId: "artifactory")
    }
...
```

The project itself is a Java project built with Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'maven'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-websocket:5.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.37'
    
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'example-client'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releasesRepoUrl = "$buildDir/mavenOut/release"
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = "$buildDir/mavenOut/snapshot"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Ultimately, we end up with 5 files that need to get deployed (the timestamps change on each build of course):

- example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1.jar
- example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1-javadoc.jar
- example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1-sources.jar
- example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1.module
- example-client-0.0.1-20200817.130343-1.pom

The Maven repository (maven-dev) within Artifactory is set up with the following settings:

- Checksum policy: Verify against client checksums
- Maven Snapshot Version Behavior: Unique
- Max Unique Snapshots:
- Handle Releases: unchecked
- Handle Snapshots: checked
- Suppress POM Consistency Checks: checked

I'm hoping that someone else has deployed a project like this to an Artifactory repo to point out what's going wrong. We've used Artifactory extensively for a number of years but not in the context of deploying snapshot builds to a Maven repository.

**EDIT:** I have narrowed down the issue to the fact that we're trying to upload the *-sources.jar in addition to the main jar and the *-javadoc.jar. If I update the exclude filter in the file spec to the following then the publish works flawlessly as expected:

```
"excludePatterns": ["*maven-metadata.xml","*.sha1","*.sha256","*.sha512","*.md5","*sources.jar"],
```

So something about the sources.jar getting published is throwing it off, any ideas?

**EDIT 2:** Well, excluding the sources jar worked for several builds then it started failing again with the same error. It will work for a build or two then fail for a while, then back to a few successes it seems.

**EDIT 3:** I also tried deploying via the Artifactory Gradle syntax rather than the more generic `rtUpload` approach. The Gradle build runs and the buildinfo publishes but no artifacts are uploaded.

** EDIT 4:**
I got it working based on suggestions below. I also updated the Artifactory Jenkins plugin to the latest. Here's the snippet from the Jenkinsfile that ended up working just in case someone else runs into a similar issue.

```
   stage('Artifactory Config') {
        steps {
            rtBuildInfo(maxBuilds: 10, deleteBuildArtifacts: true)
            
            rtGradleDeployer(
                id: "rtDeployer",
                serverId: "artifactory",
                releaseRepo: "gradle-release",
                snapshotRepo: "gradle-dev"
            )
            
            rtGradleResolver(
                id: "rtResolver",
                serverId: "artifactory",
                repo: "maven"
            )
        }
    }

    stage('Build Client'){
        steps {
            echo "invoking gradle"

            rtGradleRun(
                tasks: "artifactoryPublish",
                useWrapper: true,
                deployerId: "rtDeployer",
                resolverId: "rtResolver"
            )
            
            rtPublishBuildInfo(serverId: "artifactory")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest building and deploying Gradle artifacts using the dedicated [Gradle integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-GradleBuildswithArtifactory) offered in the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin.

This might prevent issues like those you are facing now since it is developed specifically for Gradle builds, unlike the generic command (`rtUpload`) you are currently using.

See this [Jenkinsfile example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/gradle-example/Jenkinsfile) to learn how to easily use this integration in your pipeline.

Comment: I just tried using the Gradle integration commands rather than the more generic `rtUpload`. The gradle build runs and the buildinfo is published but no artifacts are uploaded. Any thoughts on that? I updated my post to include what I did with the `rtGradleRun` style.

Comment: @Kettch19 try changing your 'tasks' to 'artifactoryPublish'

Comment: Thanks, that got things to publish using that method. However, the sources and javadoc JARs are not getting published via this method, is there a way with `rtGradleRun`/`rtGradleDeployer` to make those get deployed as well? If I ignored the sources/javadoc JARs when using the original `rtUpload` method then that worked the same as the `rtGradleRun` seems to currently.

Comment: Nevermind, I updated the Artifactory Jenkins plugin and now the sources/javadocs JAR are getting included correctly.

Comment: @Kettch19 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on error log snippet, I could see that the error is related to the deadlock in the DB transactions. I think Artifactory is running with the default derby DB.
The below error log snippet tells that there was deadlock situation in Derby,

> Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: A lock could not be obtained due to a deadlock, cycle of locks and waiters is:
> Lock : ROW, NODES, (2975,6)
> Waiting XID : {230127895, S} , APP, SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = ? AND node_path = ? AND depth = ?
> Granted XID : {230127897, X}
> Lock : ROW, NODES, (991,272)
> Waiting XID : {230127897, S} , APP, SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = ? AND node_path = ? AND depth = ?
> Granted XID : {230127895, X}

I had a similar JenkinFile which deploys Artifacts to Artifactory and never faced this issue. I believe a simple restart of Artifactory should be enough to remove the Derby DB from the deadlock state.

Comment: We've actually restarted Artifactory multiple times and even upgraded our instance from 6.x to 7.6.2 recently as well to try and solve this issue and regardless the first time we try to do the deploy for this it immediately creates the deadlock.